# Отключение 404 ошибки сервера

Tags: php

Есть адрес, введенный в адресную строку и распознанный сервером, например,

```
http://site.ru/article?id=32
```

Сервер берет из этого адреса все кроме доменного имени:

```
article?id=32
```

И в зависимости от "имени страницы" вызывает php-скрипт, генерирующий ее разметку. В данном случае, это `article.php` с параметром `id=32`. Вместо `article` в адресе может быть указана и другая страница.

Проблема в том, что при такой записи сервер выдает ошибку `Object not found (404)`, и дело до моего index.php даже не доходит. На сайте (index.php) есть некий алгоритм, вызывающий, в зависимости от адреса, тот или иной php-скрипт для генерации разметки страницы, и он же определяет: если переданный адрес не соответствует некоей маске, то эта страница считается несуществующей (404).

Насколько я понимаю, сервер даже не вызывает мой index.php в случае подобной "ошибки". Как это обычно обходится? Вроде как, `http://site.ru/forum' на сайтах традиционно 404 ошибки не выдает, и по этому адресу нормально отображается форум. Как это реализовано?

Comment: вебсервер nginx или apache?

Comment: Invision, apache.

Comment: Если стоит Apache то вам нужен mod_rewrite, если Nginx  то это location и rewrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для apache воспользуйтесь модулем mod_rewrite

Установка под linux (выполнить в консоли):

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

В корне проекта в файле `.htaccess` прописываем:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Закрываем доступ к скрытым файлам
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Закрываем директории вашего приложения от чтения (пропишите свои через | )
# RewriteRule ^(?:vendor|views|lib)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Если по ссылке обнаружен файл или директория, то обходим index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Для остальных вариантов URL исполнять index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

Далее пишите свою реализацию роутинга

Comment: Для роутов вариант посмотреть в сторону https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute